# How to play mp4 JavaFx MediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx

I have a mediaPlayer application with javafx, I can send one MediaSource from one controller to another, but the mp4 file does not play on the controller. There are no error or whatsoever, it just stays blank.

I tried to System.Out.print the source of the send media, and it is correct, if I click on the source windows 10 plays the video. Can maybe someone look over it or is there a limit on what javafx can play and what not?

Controller and Method to send a mediaPath to the player.

```
public void videoLoop() {
        File videoDirectory = new File("src\\ressources\\videos");
        File[] listOfFiles = videoDirectory.listFiles();
        File imgDirectory = new File("src\\ressources\\thumbnails");
        File[] imglistOfFiles = imgDirectory.listFiles();

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <=  listOfFiles.length - 1; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j <= imglistOfFiles.length -1 ; j++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].getName().replaceAll("(\\..+)$","").equals
                        (imglistOfFiles[j].getName().replaceAll("(\\..+)$",""))) {
                        ImageView imgView = new ImageView();
                        Image img = new Image("file:" + imglistOfFiles[j].getAbsolutePath());
                        imgView.setImage(img);
                    int finalJ1 = j;
                    mediaPath ="src\\ressources\\videos\\" + imglistOfFiles[finalJ1].getName().replaceAll("(\\..+)$","")  + ".mp4";
                    imgView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {

     selectionMedia = new Media(Paths.get(mediaPath).toUri().toString());
                        var window = utilities.viewSwitcher.getWindow(event);
                        var loader = new FXMLLoader();
                        loader.setLocation(videoSelectionController.class.getResource("/view/videoPlayerView.fxml"));
                        VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController = new VideoPlayerController();
                        videoPlayerController.setMedia(selectionMedia);
                        videoPlayerController.videoPlay();

                        try {
                            window.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        window.sizeToScene();

                    });
                    buttonBox.getChildren().add(imgView);


                }
```

Method to play the video

```
public void videoPlay(){

        var loader = new FXMLLoader(VideoSelectionController.class.getResource("/view/videoSelection.fxml"));
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        VideoSelectionController controller = loader.getController();
        videoPlayer = new MediaView();
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(this.media);
        videoPlayer.setMediaPlayer(player);
        player.play();

    }
```

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: There is missing code before `selectionMedia`

Comment: I have edited my code (name conventions should be now correct I hope) and put the missing code part inside my post

Answer (score 0):

Hello Jizang Depending on which version of JavaFX you are using support for media formats can vary. If you are using JavaFX 8 then you are unable to use MP4 files with the MediaPlayer.
You will instead have to use one of the following formats for JavaFX 8

"Audio: MP3; AIFF containing uncompressed PCM; WAV containing uncompressed PCM; MPEG-4 multimedia container with Advanced Audio Coding (AAC) audio
Video: FLV containing VP6 video and MP3 audio; MPEG-4 multimedia container with H.264/AVC (Advanced Video Coding) video compression
"
-Direct quote from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm accessed 10/14/2020

I was unable to find information for the mediaplayer on later versions of JavaFX
More info on the topic can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm)

-Coder5986